# JS Как узнать index элемента объекта в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Предположим имеется массив такого вида

```js
games: [
    {
      id: 1342,
      gameName: "Футбол",
      gameUrl: "football",
      gameAdded: "2021-02-11T15:04:23.000Z",
      gameSeo:
        "<p>football от foot «ступня» + ball «мяч») — командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами или другими частями тела (кроме рук) большее количество раз, чем команда соперника. В настоящее время самый популярный и массовый вид спорта в мире.</p>"
    },
    {
      id: 234232,
      gameName: "Basketball",
      gameUrl: "basketball",
      gameSeo:
        "<p>Баскетбо́л (англ. basket «корзина» + ball «мяч») — спортивная командная игра с мячом, в которой мяч забрасывают руками в кольцо соперника. В баскетбол играют две команды, каждая из которых состоит из пяти полевых игроков (замены не ограничены).</p>"
    },
    {
      id: 3234234,
      gameName: "Хоккей",
      gameUrl: "hockey",
      gameSeo:
        "<p>Хокке́й с ша́йбой, хокке́й на льду — командная спортивная игра на льду, заключающаяся в противоборстве двух команд на коньках, которые, передавая шайбу клюшками, стремятся забросить её наибольшее количество раз в ворота соперника и не пропустить в свои.</p>"
    }
  ]
  
  let el = "hockey";  //// То по чему мы ищем
  //// Как узнать индекс текущего элемента в массиве? (2)
```

Как определить под каким индексом данные относящиеся к этой игре относительно массива?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точнее будет сделать так. По вашему топику. Не gameName а gameUrl

```js
   let games = [
    {
      id: 1342,
      gameName: "Футбол",
      gameUrl: "football",
      gameAdded: "2021-02-11T15:04:23.000Z",
      gameSeo:
        "<p>football от foot «ступня» + ball «мяч») — командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами или другими частями тела (кроме рук) большее количество раз, чем команда соперника. В настоящее время самый популярный и массовый вид спорта в мире.</p>"
    },
    {
      id: 234232,
      gameName: "Basketball",
      gameUrl: "basketball",
      gameSeo:
        "<p>Баскетбо́л (англ. basket «корзина» + ball «мяч») — спортивная командная игра с мячом, в которой мяч забрасывают руками в кольцо соперника. В баскетбол играют две команды, каждая из которых состоит из пяти полевых игроков (замены не ограничены).</p>"
    },
    {
      id: 3234234,
      gameName: "Хоккей",
      gameUrl: "hockey",
      gameSeo:
        "<p>Хокке́й с ша́йбой, хокке́й на льду — командная спортивная игра на льду, заключающаяся в противоборстве двух команд на коньках, которые, передавая шайбу клюшками, стремятся забросить её наибольшее количество раз в ворота соперника и не пропустить в свои.</p>"
    }
  ]
  
  let el = "hockey";  //// То по чему мы ищем
  let result = games.findIndex(item=>item.gameUrl === el);
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 games.findIndex((element) => element.gameName === 'hockey');
```

Как-то так